# Select a radio button dynamically

Tags: javascript, function, alert

I need to select a radio button dynamically.

i) I have created few radio buttons dynamically, i.e. in a function using:

```
function funcName()
{
    Something.innerHTML = '<input type = "radio" name = "rName" id = "1" />' + '<input   type = "radio" name = "rName" id = "2" />' + '<input type = "radio" name = "rName" id = "3" />';

}
```

ii) I need to select a radio button dynamically, in another function:

```
function funcNAme(someVar)
{
    document.getElementById(someVar).checked = true;
}
```

But this does not work, i.e. the radio button doesn not get selected. However, 'disabled' works fine. 
Also:

```
alert(someVar);
```

returns the appropriate desired value.

Comment: your function should be working fine ... [check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2dmSz/1/)

Comment: It maybe related to my second comment in my answer - about having IDs set to numbers - not a good practice and not valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is as follows :

```
element.checked = true;
```

So you need to use

```
document.getElementById(someVar).checked = true;
```

See here -> [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement)

Working example -> http://jsfiddle.net/p5yca/

And please please do not use numbers for IDs of elements -> http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: Well its working fine in my example - what browser is it failing in ? how are you triggering the function ? what errors are you getting ?

Comment: Using ff. Not necessarily trigeering a function. Define a function that creates a radio button. Use another function to select it. Not an error actually, the radio button does not get selected

Comment: @ElClassico add a link to your page or create a http://jsfiddle.net/ its the only way we are going to be able to help you

Comment: @ElClassico and thats exactly the way its written on your site - where is fails ? same IDs / function names / order of JS ?

Comment: everything is the same. I used the latter statement, i.e. selecting the button just after I create them, but of no use. alert(x.value) works fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine:

```
function checkRadio(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}

function createRadios()
{
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<input type = "radio" name = "rName" id = "1" />' + '<input   type = "radio" name = "rName" id = "2" />' + '<input type = "radio" name = "rName" id = "3" />';
}

createRadios();
checkRadio("2");
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/LHyQT/2/

Comment: @ElClassico I've updated the fiddle so it's almost identical to your example an it works fine. What browser are you using? (I tested on chrome, ff and ie8 and it works fine)

Comment: use ff. Is it because I create the buttons dynamically, I encounter this error?

Comment: Used: ...Id('1').checked and ...Id('a non integer name').checked = true. but none work

Comment: @ElClassico add you **exact** code here http://jsfiddle.net/ then report back here ... must be something wrong with your syntax / method

Comment: I agree with @ManseUK Must be some other problem with your code as this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the `checked` attribute on the `innerHTML` attribute, not on the DOM element itself; this should do the trick:

```
document.getElementById("id").checked = true;
```